# Is TSA Pre check a security risk?

Tags: safety, airport, tsa

As we have seen through history, many times, despicable acts of terror and violence have been committed by just "normal" unsuspecting people, that for whatever reason (hate, outburst of anger, mental sickness, etc) something switches in their mind and they commit these acts without anybody expecting it(*they were a lovely couple, he was a quiet kid, he looked like a normal neighbor, etc*)

This brings me to the point, when a passenger gets to the airport why would you allow one group to go trough a less meticulous screening (TSA Pre) if they could be carrying something harmful.

And if the TSA Pre group is still screened to some extent then why not use the same process for everybody else?

A person that was totally peaceful yesterday, today could want to do harm.

Comment: To an evil smuggler, airport security screening is just an inconvenience.  To a terrorist, a security checkpoint is a convenient target.  The TSA's purpose is to please the voters of the legislators who created the TSA.

Comment: That is right, I remember what happened at Brussels airport in 2016, they didn't even had to go trough security, they did their thing right there. That's why I don't like agglutination of people, its the perfect target for terrorists.

Comment: The idea that somehow a "normal" person "just suddenly flips" and commits a terrorist act is almost never true. Most terrorist acts are planned.

Comment: When you say the "same process," are you proposing greater screening for all, or less screening for TSA Pre-check passengers?

Comment: @MichaelHall less screening. But what I'm trying to say is that whatever process it is, it should be the same for everybody. ultimately I think TSA should make efficient/faster the normal process instead of creating another different process for a different group as if they were not also humans with the faculty to commit evil.

Comment: OK, but do you not agree that some people are less risk than others?  I mean, I agree that all people are equal in the eyes of the law, God, etc. but there is no denying that some elements of society are more bent on crime and mayhem than others.  To deny that fact is actually rather naive.  The current process is aligned with reality more so than what you would propose, and provides benefits to low risk frequent travelers who are willing to subject themselves to heightened scrutiny.

Comment: @MichaelHall People are definitely different risk. Some people are 100% risk, others 0%, and almost no one's in between. The relevant question is whether TSA Pre-check is only passable by the 0% risk people.

Comment: @Therac - No one is "zero risk". Even those pre cleared by TSA. Just "less risk".

Comment: @WPNSGuy I am zero risk: I've never taken to the air with the intent to commit an act of terror, not will I ever.

Comment: @Therac - Prove it. Prove it to the security guy standing between you and the aircraft. That is what the precheck is for.

Comment: @WPNSGuy Exactly. I know I'm zero risk, but the guard doesn't. The purpose of all checks is to learn this. So the question is whether TSA Pre obtains the right information to filter out the 1-in-billions terrorist.

Comment: @Therac - And the "pre check" is to do just that...check and approve you before the line at the airport. Allowing you to skip some of the stuff at the line. Is it perfect? Of course not. So...propose something different.

Comment: @WPNSGuy I'm not campaigning - just commenting on the question.

Comment: @MichaelHall definitely yes if we look at the numbers you are right, however doesn't mean it can't happen. Even the pilot himself can be suicidal(remember the 2015 GermanWings suicide pilot that killed everybody after the copilot went to the restrooms), which created the procedure to always have 2 persons in the cockpit. My point is, in that same way, that we should all be playing at the same level and not allow someone to have an "advantage" (TSA Pre) over another group of people (Non Pre)

Comment: And my point is that everybody should NOT be playing at the same level because not everybody is the same level of risk.

Answer (score 4):

> A person that was totally peaceful yesterday, today could want to do harm.

A person who previously went through and passed a security check is *less likely* to go off today.

Just like needing a security clearance for a job. Not 100% guaranteed to never ever go rogue, but *less likely*.

Comment: I don't buy this answer at all. People with a gripe can build up resentment over time and plan to commit atrocities later, E.G. [Killdozer guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_Heemeyer), [Mandalay Bay guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Las_Vegas_shooting), etc. Even the [9/11 hijackers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijackers_in_the_September_11_attacks) had obviously cleared security before in order to get into the US. There's got to be another reason for pre-checks, IMO.

Comment: @DannyBeckett The question did not ask for the reason precheck exists.  Precheck exists to collect a fee.  It's also a convenience for frequent fliers who are also frequent donors to political campaigns.